# How to count number of distinct pairs per partition in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, count, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I want to get the # of distinct pair combinations per `level` in my table.

Sample Data:

```
level       group_no    item_no
oiegown     1           1
oiegown     1           2
oiegown     1           2
oiegown     1           3
oiegown     2           1
wefwefw     1           1
wefwefw     2           2
```

My Attempt:

Wanted to do something like

```
COUNT(DISTINCT group_no, item_no) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY level)
AS item_count
```

Expected Output:

```
level       item_count
oiegown     4           
wefwefw     2
```

But seems that `COUNT()` only accepts one argument in BigQuery. How can I modify my query to get my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join both column into one Text, and count the concatenated text

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(group_no, item_no)) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY level)
AS item_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query for the expected out:

```sql
SELECT level, COUNT(DISTINCT group_no || item_no) AS item_count
  FROM sample_table
 GROUP BY 1;
```

[image]